# Question about definition of a limit

Tags: limits

For the formal definition of a limit, why do we require that

$$0 < |x-a| < \delta$$

Why do we need the "0 <" part? Isn't it true that absolute values are always greater than 0?
What is the significance of including this?

Comment: No, absolute values are $\ge 0$. We don't want to take into account what happens at $x=a$. The function may or may not even be defined there. And we don't care what its value is, if it is.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value is greater than **or equal to** zero.

The formal definition of a limit is written precisely to work outside of the case in which $x = a$.

E.g. consider an example of a function $f(x) = 0$ for all $ x\neq 0$, $f(0) = 1$. Because we are not considering $f(0)$ for $a=0$, we can talk about the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$, which then exists and equals $L = 0$: For any $\varepsilon > 0$, we take $\delta = 1$. Then all $f(x)$ where $0 < |x| < 1$ have value $0$, because $f(0)$ is not considered. And so $|f(x) - L| = |0 - 0| = 0 < \varepsilon$ for all such $x$. We cannot make all $f(x)$ close to $L$, only all $f(x)$ for $x \neq a$.

Answer (score 1):

It is '$0 <|x-a| $' , not '$0 \le |x-a|$'. This suggests that :
$$|x-a| \neq 0 \implies x \neq a$$

Id est, $x$ tends to $a$ but is never ever exactly equal to $a$.

Also, absolute values aren't always positive, they are always **NON-NEGATIVE**.